# Compiler Error ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am facing the following problem.

> CS0016: Could not write to output file
>   'c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\ac7\73452b9a\5e5b0927\App_Code.j0itviqn.dll' -- 'Access is
>   denied.'

After Googling for 2 days, i gave PERMISSIONS to NETWORK SERVICES in my "Temporary ASPNET Files" and TEMP folder in %Systemroot%.
i also checked the "Environmental Variables > System variables" by right clicking MY COMPUTER.
Disabled my ANTI VIRUS and still facing the problem.

do any one have any other solution ?

Comment: Perhaps the file is locked by another process? Can you remove the file manually?

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447879/duplicate-type-error/8448036#8448036 gives a full run down of steps to clear out caches

Answer (score 2):

I had solved the same issue.
Check that group IIS_IUSRS (or other IIS user group that you use) has full control permission to:
"c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files"
and
"c:\WINDOWS\Temp"

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried deleting everything in your temporary asp.net folder?

Also, try cleaning and rebuilding the solution by right clicking on your solution in the solution explorer in Visual Studio.

Comment: yes. i deleted all folders from temporary asp.net folder and rebuild the solution. but still facing the same problem.

Comment: I generally only ever saw this error on one project I had that was a Web Site as opposed to a Web Application. I found that by removing the generated *App_Code*.dll's that this worked for me. Could you check the published BIN folder for multiple AppCode.dll's (if you find them delete them). Can't think of anything else, sorry.